# Proof about Levels in connected graphs with minimum degree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For a connected Graph $G=(V,E)$ with minimum degree $\delta$ and diameter $D=d(x,y)$, formally prove that $k_0+k_1\geqslant\delta +1$ and $k_{D-1}+k_D\geqslant\delta +1$ which implies that $k_{j-1}+k_j+k_{j+1}\geqslant\delta +1$ ($3\leqslant j\leqslant D)$, where $k_i$ is the cardinal of $L_i:=\{ w\in V:d(w,x)=i\}$.

The only thing I can come up with is that if the latter wasn't true, not all vertices would have a degree of at least $\delta$.
I am not sure that this is sufficient. Many papers, such as the 1987 paper by Erdös, Pach, Pollack and Tuza, take this observation for granted, so perhaps it is sufficient. Nevertheless, I'd like to see if someone can prove this in a more intuitive way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a vertex in level $i$. Such a vertex and all its neighbors are contained in levels $_{−1}$, $_i$, and $_{i+1}$. The result follows.